# Having trouble solving part two of an equation:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Part one consisted of proving that 
$$\frac{x-1}{x-3} = 1+ \frac{2}{x-3}$$
I completed this and here is my working:
$$let \frac{x-1}{x-3}= LHS$$
$$RHS=\frac{x-3}{x-3} + \frac{2}{x-3}$$
$$\frac{2+(x-3)}{(x-3)}$$
$$\frac {x-3+2}{x-3}$$
$$\frac {x-1}{x-3} = LHS$$

Part two then asks me to hence solve:

$$\frac{x-1}{x-3}-\frac{x-3}{x-5} = \frac{x-5}{x-7}−\frac{x-7}{x-9}$$

I have attempted to sub in part one into part two but my answers always turn out to be incorrect. 
Any tips in the matter would be much appreciated.

I'd like to thank anyone who comments and answers in advance, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by realizing you can get a common denominator (and simplify once you have):
$$
-\frac{4}{(x-5)(x-3)}=-\frac{4}{(x-9)(x-7)}.
$$
Now take the reciprocal of both sides:
$$
-\frac{1}{4}(x-5)(x-3)=-\frac{1}{4}(x-9)(x-7).
$$
Now expand out the terms on the left- and right-hand sides:
$$
-\frac{x^2}{4}+2x-\frac{15}{4}=-\frac{x^2}{4}+4x-\frac{63}{4}.
$$
To make it easy to solve for $x$ (i.e., try to solve for when one of the sides equals $0$), subtract $-\frac{x^2}{4}+4x-\frac{63}{4}$ from both sides, obtaining
$$
12-2x=0 \Longleftrightarrow 2(6-x)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x=6.
$$
Thus, your equality is true when $x=6$.

Comment: Before taking the reciprocal you have to check what happens when both sides are equal to 0 and then assume they are not 0 (this is for avoiding missing solutions). You must also check the solutions at the end to make sure there are no extraneous solutions.

Comment: @user314 You amuse me. Maybe you were the one person who downvoted this? Trying to compensate for something?

Comment: Yes, I downvoted it, and that's because it is not fully correct (reasons above).

Comment: @user314 Yes, it is fully correct. I don't spell out *every* single detail. You have another solution for it?

Comment: This is exactly what can easily cause extraneous or missing solutions. These are extremely important details that often happen when squaring both sides, multiplying both sides by something that is/can be 0, etc. E.g., $\frac{0}{x}=\frac{0}{1}$ has infinitely many solutions while $\frac{x}{0}=\frac{1}{0}$ has no solutions, and vice versa. For more details, see [the Wikipedia page for it](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions).

Comment: @user314 Seriously? You think I'm an idiot or something? I know about extraneous solutions. There's also the famously flawed proof that $0=1$, that all horses are the same color (induction), etc. Not to be snappy, but I don't appreciate the condescension and puerile downvoting, especially given your voting history.

Comment: I still feel it was worth the downvote as now the OP or others might feel they can always just take reciprocals of both sides (and also not check the solutions after doing such operations), while this is not the case if, e.g., $x-7$ were $x-5$ instead, which would give an extraneous solution.

Comment: @user314 It is not incumbent upon me to address every pedagogical nicety to give a satisfactory answer. The OP found it to be the best answer and 5 other people found it helpful as well. Maybe you should downvote Karl's answer too. Nonsense.

Comment: I have decided to remove the downvote, but I really do hope you're not going to forget to be careful with performing not-always-invertible operations to both sides of an equation.

Answer (score 2):

The hence suggests:

Let $x=x-2$ the first equation becomes 
$$ 
\frac{(x-2)-1}{(x-2)-3}  = 1+\frac{2}{(x-2)-3} \\
\frac{x-3}{x-5}=1+\frac{2}{x-5} 
$$
This process can be done with the other fractions in part 2. Notice that this will be of benefit because the $1$ will cancel because of the subtraction.
$$
1-\frac{2}{x-3}-\left(1-\frac{2}{x-5}\right)=1-\frac{2}{x-7}-\left(1-\frac{2}{x-9}\right)\\
-\frac{2}{x-3}+\frac{2}{x-5}=-\frac{2}{x-7}+\frac{2}{x-9}$$
Cancel the $2$ and simplify each side $$ \frac{-(x-5)+x-3}{(x-3)(x-5)} =\frac{-(x-9)+(x-7)}{(x-7)(x-9)}$$

Simplify  and note the numerators are equal. The fractions can therefore only be equivalent if the denominators are equal. Note that $x\neq7$ for example. $$ (x-3)(x-5)=(x-7)(x-9) \\
x^2-8x+15=x^2-16x+63 \\
8x=48\\
x=6
$$

Comment: You cannot "flip" (which means raising both sides to the power of $-1$) without first checking whether the both sides you're flipping are equal to $0$ and then assuming they are not equal to $0$ (for avoiding missing solutions) and after solving the equation checking the solutions (for determining whether there are extraneous solutions). I will not downvote you this time, but please have this in mind when doing such not-always-invertible operations.

Comment: Thank you for not down voting I had read the previous comments and perhaps should have noted eg $x=7$ might cause problems.

Comment: @Karl user314 has very high standards. Your solution is fine. You don't have to address *every* single little thing that could happen. Stay strong and ignore users like him who just intentionally try to stir up trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a difference of two each time between numerator and denominator, we can use the rearrangement you have from part 1 on each fraction in part 2.

Then, after a little simplification, you can cross-multiply your fractions and get a constant in the numerator on each side. This allows you to invert the fractions and solve.